# How to apply a custom highlight file?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, syntax-highlighting, highlight, macvim

I'm playing with Vim highlight, so I made the following (`syntax.vim`):

```
hi Comment ctermfg=DarkGray
hi LineNR ctermfg=DarkGray
hi CursorLineNR ctermfg=Red
hi String ctermfg=Gray
hi PreProc ctermfg=Brown

syn match MyOp /+/
syn match MyOp /-/
syn match MyOp /*/  containedin=comment contained
syn match MyOp /\// containedin=comment contained
syn match MyOp /&/
syn match MyOp /:/
syn match MyOp /\./
syn match MyOp /=/
hi MyOp ctermfg=LightBlue

syn match MyBrakets /</
syn match MyBrakets />/
syn match MyBrakets /(/
syn match MyBrakets /)/
syn match MyBrakets /{/
syn match MyBrakets /}/
syn match MyBrakets /\[/
syn match MyBrakets /\]/
hi MyBrakets ctermfg=Yellow

syn keyword MyNSutl utl 
hi MyNSutl ctermfg=Gray

syn keyword MyNSmmi mmi
hi MyNSmmi ctermfg=DarkBlue

syn match MySend /send_\w*/
hi MySend ctermfg=Red

syn match MyGet /get_\w*/
hi MyGet ctermfg=Magenta

syn match MyPrint /print_\w*/
hi MyPrint ctermfg=Gray

syn match MyMPI /MPI_\w*/
hi MyMPI ctermfg=LightGray
```

I was testing it with a single file, while in Vim with my .cpp file open I did `so syntax.vim` and the magic happened. So far so good.

Next step was to use it in the session I was working, `Vim -S session.vim` to open some files in split view, and `so syntax.vim`. Problem. Syntax applies to just one file, current split. So I have to repeat that to all files -  not good.

After some googling I found that correct way to proceed was to rename it to i.e. `cpp_my.vim` and put in ~/.vim/ftplugin/myplugin/. Did that, and it workds partially, some settings don't get applied. Then I went to Vim doc section 41.11 Writing a plugin. Things are getting complicated and here I'm.

The hack I did isn't general purpose, its just for the project I'm working these days. So making it a plugin don't smell good to me.

So in order to use it, the best approach is to manually `so syntax.vim` to each file? Or is there some clever alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to drop the file in `{rtp}/syntax/{ft}.vim`. Given the proximity between C and C++, I'd say in `$HOME/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim` -- in `after/` to be sure to source the standard configuration before the *improvements*.

PS: IIRC my experiments, the less `syn match` you have, the fastest highlighting will be. `match` is made to support regexes, you can then merge several of your single character patterns into a single pattern => `"[+=^&~<>:-]"`

Comment: It works if I put it on`{rtp}/syntax/cpp` not `c`.

Comment: Indeed. My mistake. It's because somewhere in my `{rtp}/syntax/cpp.vim` and `c.vim` I execute `:runtime! syntax/c-*.vim syntax/c_*.vim`. I've edited my answer.